# How to make a div hide when having same set of classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two set of div containers with input tags with same classes to both. 
only difference is when input box of each clicked the resepctive parent div will add "frame-focus" class. what i want is if input is clicked and frame-focus class is exist, hide the div which has class "panel-set" of which the focus class exist.

Please check my div containers below. please advice how to proceed this 
Ex:

```
<!--- here is 1st div container which input box is selected-->
    <div class="block">
    <div class="frame frame-focus">
    <input name="set1">
    <div class="panel-set"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

<!-- here is 2nd div -->
    <div class="block">
    <div class="frame">
    <input name="set1">
    <div class="panel-set"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Should panel-set be hidden on the div that has Frame-focus or the one that done have?

Comment: Can you give us the code you're currently using that adds `.frame-focus`?

Comment: .frame-focus .panel-set {display:none; visibility:hidden;}

Answer (score 1):

Use the child selector or the [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to hide the `.panel-set` which is a child of `.frame-focus`:

```css
.frame-focus > .panel-set {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--- here is 1st div container which input box is selected-->
<div class="block">
  <div class="frame frame-focus">
    <input name="set1">
    <div class="panel-set">1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- here is 2nd div -->
<div class="block">
  <div class="frame">
    <input name="set1">
    <div class="panel-set">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
    <div class="block">
    <div class="frame frame-focus">
    <input name="set1">
    <div class="panel-set">1</div>
    </div>
    </div>

<!-- here is 2nd div -->
    <div class="block">
    <div class="frame">
    <input name="set1">
    <div class="panel-set">2</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.panel-set').hide();
});

});
```

Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44bv1nud/4/)